# Wildcard SSL Binding to App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am a little confused as to why Azure is not letting me bind my wildcard SSL certificate to my app?

I've added some screenshots to help illustrate my problem below...

---

### Wildcard Certificate

Here is my wildcard SSL certificate, properly installed on the App Service Plan...

￼[image: SSL Blade]

---

### SSL Binding Works Here

I'm able to bind it only to the root domain...

[image: SSL Bindings Blade]

---

### SSL Binding Does Not Work Here

Here is an attempt to bind it to a sub-domain. The portal is not allowing me to add it...

It states:

```
No certificates match the selected hostname
```

[image: SSL Bindings Blade]

I have not found any documentation stating that this kind of setup using wildcard SSL certficates are **not** supported, unless I missed something?

*Note: I have tried both the classic portal and the new one with no success.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because your wildcard certificate DNS are not valid to match your AppService URL. You should take a look at accepted wildcards used by server certificates, especially the "[No accepted Wildcard Samples](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/258858/accepted-wildcards-used-by-server-certificates-for-server-authentication)".

For example:

www.example.abc.com **doesn't match** the wildcard *.abc.com

name.api.mydomain.com **doesn't match** the wildcard *.mydomain.com

name-api.mydomain.com **matches** *.mydomain.com